# Differentiability of Sin inverse

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

My book says that trigonometric functions and their inverses are differentiable in their domain.

I am looking for $y=\sin^{-1}(x)$ to verify the same. $\sin^{-1}(x)$ has its  domain in interval [-1.1]. But if I look at the derivative of $\sin^{−1}(x)$ as follows

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}}$$

If my $x$ is $-1$ or $+1$ then the expression will becomes infinity. So I can say that it is not differentiable at $+1$ and $-1$. But I am contradicting my book. Am I going wrong somewhere in understanding this?

Comment: I suggest you do a search on math.SE, and there are plenty discussion about arcsin(x). BTW, the formula you provided about the derivative is not correct.

Comment: Thank you.I was a mistake.I have updated it now

Comment: You are right: the arcsine is not differentiable at $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=1$.

The statement made in you book is incomplete.  A similar but correct statement would be that if $f(x)$ is an elementary trig function and $[a,b]$ is a closed interval, and if for all $x \in [a,b] : \left.\frac{df}{dt}\right|_{t=x} \neq 0$ then $f^{-1}(x)$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$.

For the case of $\sin x$ on  $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ (so  that the range of $\sin^{-1}$ is $[-1,1]$, that non-zero derivative condition does not hold at either endpoint $\pm\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the book : Concepts, Problems and Solutions in School Calculus (by Lev Tarasov and Chandra Shekhar Kumar)

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]